# The idea for a nice MYSQL print data

Tags: php, mysql

e.g.

```
id - Name - Surname - Phone - Married
1 - Ann - AnnS - 123 - No
2 - Mary - MarryS - [empty] - Yes
3 - Jane - JaneS - 321 - [empty]
```

Now I want to take a record by **id** and print the info smth like this (**CHANGE THE ROW NAME TO SMTH ELSE and IF THE ROW IS EMPTY - NOT TO SHOW THE ROW AT ALL**):

```
SELECT * FROM `girls` WHERE `id`='1'

The girls name - Ann 
The girls surname - AnnS
The girls number - 123
Is the girl married? - No
```

/-/

```
SELECT * FROM `girls` WHERE `id`='2'

The girls name - Ann
The girls surname - AnnS
Is the girl married? - No
```

*How is it easier to do without overloading the server (there are about 130 rows in a table) ?*

Comment: Have you any PHP you can show?

Comment: what for? I need not to show empty rows and to change the name of a row - just dont know how to do it easier.

Answer (score 1):

select them all at once

```
$sql = "select * from girls";
```

then iterate over the result set in php

```
$result = mysql_query($mysql);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    echo "The girls name - ".$row['name'].";
     //....
}
```

Comment: There will be a list of products (e.g. cell phones) and when i click one of them - I`ll make a query to take 1;

Comment: Then why are you worried about overloading the server?

Comment: I need to check every row if it is not empty and if it is not - I have to check if it is YES or NO and to print an image or, if it is not YES or NO - print it as it is.
There can be 10 people, that will click an item at one time - so 10 queries, 20 checks..